# How to auto re-direct from other url?

Tags: javascript, html, css, redirect, dreamweaver

I'm writing for a condizionale auto re-direct url, but it doesn't works. I tried with two methods:

```
<script>
      function mobileDevice()
        {
        $type = $_SERVER[‘HTTP_USER_AGENT’];
        if(strpos((string)$type, “Windows Phone”) != false || strpos((string)$type, “iPhone”) != false || strpos((string)$type, “Android”) != false)
        return true;
        else
        return false;
        }
        if(mobileDevice() == true)
        header(‘Location: https://www.organization.org/mobile/index_mobile.htm‘);
</script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      if (screen.width <= 414) {
        document.location = "index.htm";
        <script language=javascript>
    if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
       location.replace("https://www.organization.org/mobile/index_mobile.htm");
    }
          </script>
      }
    </script>
```

As I yet announced, no one of this works, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain Javascript you should assign the value location instead of using method to redirect. *replace* method won't save in history the change of url.

```
window.location = "https://www.organization.org/mobile/index_mobile.htm";
```

Also you are nesting two  tags in your second approach. The correct code would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      if (screen.width <= 414) {
        document.location = "index.htm";
        if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
          location.replace("https://www.organization.org/mobile/index_mobile.htm");
        }
      }
</script>
```

Comment: If i try with: <head>
<script>
 if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
       <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; URL=http://www.organization.org/mobile/index_mobile.htm">
<meta name="keywords" content="automatic redirection">
    }
 </script>
</head> no works anyway

Comment: You cannot put meta tags inside a script block. This is not how it works. The meta tags should be inside the head tag and you can add a script tag with code that will be executed, but only with Javascript inside it.
`<head> <script> if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) { window.location= "organization.org/mobile/index_mobile.htm"; } </script> </head>`

Comment: oh... that's why. Thank you so much!